# HTTP GET/POST requests on an HTTPs website

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, https

The problem: Some people send `GET`, `POST` Request over `HTTP`. (The Website use `HTTPS` and theoretically not accept `HTTP`)

I try to prevent this with the following updates, unfortunately without success.

**PHP - Check for HTTP's connection**

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
{
   //connection are HTTP's load site...
}
```

**Htaccess - Redirects**

```
RewriteEngine On
# check for https conneciton
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# www entfernen - domain replaced with xxx (privecy)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://xxx/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# check port
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewroteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L, R=301]
```

**My reasoning is:**
A bot may be sending a form from another server over an HTTP connection.
Why now htaccess doesn't work or the PHP script is a mystery to me.
As info: For normal visitors, everything works as desired.

**Server answer**

That was the Request from the (attacker)

```
"GET /site/Kontakt/ HTTP/1.0" 301 706
"POST /site/Kontakt/ HTTP/1.0" 200 16247
"GET /site/Kontakt/ HTTP/1.0" 301 706
"GET /site/Kontakt/ HTTP/1.0" 200 19647
```

Comment: Whats the response you get when you sent request using the bot?

Comment: The bot requests are not made by me. I have added part of the Log.

Comment: For those cases i think using https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/ or generating tokens for each form would be a good idea to prevent those

Comment: At least two of those GET request you have shown from the log, appear to get answered with a redirect - the status code is 301. Not sure what the actual problem is supposed to be here - or whether there actually is one in the first place.

Comment: And if you got one request with a 301 response and 706 bytes returned, immediately followed by a second one, that gets a 200 OK, and 16247 bytes returned … that would be even more indication that everything is working as it should, and that you are imagining problems where there aren’t any. The 706 bytes would then probably be the default “error document” that usually accompanies a 301 response, and the  16247 bytes the actual content of the requested page, this time requested via HTTPS as instructed, and therefor not redirected again.

Comment: I'm very careful at the moment, but we had guests who did some damage, so I'm currently following small clues. A normal call simply looks different: "GET HTTP / 1.1" 200 5668 "POST HTTP / 1.1" 200 4865
So if you think that it is not a problem, then I'm a little reassured.

Comment: Whether someone can “do damage” to your site by making a specific request, has rather little to do with whether that request is made via HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: yeah but i want 100% be sure that all users use HTTPs and for the first look didnt was the case.